# How to write a text file from Dictionary, where each key is a new line?

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe, text

Here is my code:

```
#creating a list of tweets ID and a dictionary with the values
tweet_ids = list(df1.tweet_id)
tweet_data = {}

for tweet in tweet_ids[:5]:
    try:
        tweet_status = api.get_status(tweet, tweet_mode='extended')
        id_str = tweet_status.id_str
        retweet_count = tweet_status.retweet_count
        favorite_count = tweet_status.favorite_count
        tweet_data[id_str] = retweet_count, favorite_count
    except:
        print("Error for: " + str(tweet))
```

The result

Input `tweet_status`

Output:

```
{'892420643555336193': (8374, 38224),
'892177421306343426': (6181, 32766),
'891815181378084864': (4090, 24675),
'891689557279858688': (8512, 41548),
'891327558926688256': (9219, 39740)}
```

So far so good.... but when I create a text file, it creates a file like this:

```
{'892420643555336193': (8374, 38223), '892177421306343426': (6181, 32765), '891815181378084864': (4090, 24675), '891689557279858688': (8513, 41546), '891327558926688256': (9220, 39737)}
```

Code used to create the file:

```
f = open('tweet_json.txt', 'w')
f.write(str(tweet_data))
f.close()
```

Comment: If it outputs correctly to stdout, you could just redirect stdout to the text file.  For example execute "python mycode.py > myfile.txt" from the command line.  Alternatively, @slider has a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json.dumps` to format the JSON string before writing to your file:

```
import json

f = open('tweet_json.txt', 'w')
f.write(json.dumps(tweet_data, indent=2))
f.close()
```

The file output then is as follows:

```
{
  "892420643555336193": [
    8374,
    38224
  ],
  "892177421306343426": [
    6181,
    32766
  ],
  "891815181378084864": [
    4090,
    24675
  ],
  "891689557279858688": [
    8512,
    41548
  ],
  "891327558926688256": [
    9219,
    39740
  ]
}
```

Comment: thank you so much.
Now, if I want to create a dataframe with 3 columns, where column 1 is the key, columns 2 and 3 are the values... how should I do?

Comment: @LeandroBaruch that seems somewhat unrelated. I would suggest you ask a separate question for that.